# Is there a run through breakpoints option in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

I'm not talking about Disable All Breakpoints or Start without Debugging.

For example, I have my breakpoints set, including some in loops.  I get to a point where I just want the code to run through, without having to disable or toggle off each breakpoint.  I want the breakpoints to stay enabled for my next run, but I just want the current execution to complete.

If not, definitely nice to have.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Debug -> Detach All which detaches the debugger but leaves the process running.